# Is there a way to "replay" a packet capture of a smtp session for the purpose of debugging?

Tags: smtp, email-server, packet-capture, encoding, charset

I'm troubleshooting a smtp issue involving character-set encoding and it's extremely difficult to involve the end user. I have a packet capture of an incoming smtp session that results in problematic behavior but if I try to copy/paste the mime source from wireshark, the issue doesn't occur.

I'm reasonably certain that the difference in my testing is that I'm copying the *strings* in the packet capture from the Wireshark "follow tcp stream" output and that's not necessarily the bit-for-bit accurate copy of the data as it arrived on the wire.

So my question is this: how can I get an EXACT copy of the bit-for-bit SMTP data and send it again for reproduction purposes? Is there a way to "replay" a transmission?

Answer (score 4):

I hate to turn this into a discussion about tools, rather than about the technology involved, but you may want to look into the use of [`tcpreplay`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpreplay) which takes `.pcap` files and replays them even at the same speed 
that they originally came in.

Comment: ...that moment when you find out that there's a tool literally named exactly after the functionality you're seeking. :-( I promise I really did Google before posting!

Comment: @MikeB That moment when I realize I fail at linking things in markdown.

Comment: tcpreplay(1) manual in section "Bugs": "In most cases, you can not replay traffic back to/at a server.". There are multiple problems like port number the server gets from accept(2), randomised TCP sequence numbers etc.

Comment: So... sounds like this won't necessarily help then.  Is there an alternative?